# Reindex causes configurable product images to disappear?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, product-images, magmi, reindex

**Peculiar problem:** We're using Magmi to import configurable & simple products and product images. We have about 6-7 images linked to the configurable product. These images should be displayed on the category page & product-detail page.

When we first import the products and look them up in the backoffice, everything seems fine: simple products linked to configurable product, all images linked to configurable product, product linked to category etc.

Then we navigate to the category, but we don't see any images. Then we look in backoffice again, and product images of the configurable product have been removed!

After some investigation, we can reproduce the issue when we just upload images in the backoffice, manually, to the product. After doing so and refreshing the backoffice page, the image(s) are displayed correctly .. but after reindexing, the image is removed again.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the Magmi insert the image directly in the database.

If this is the case, and you are using the same images for the rest of the products, Magento will clear the images that are duplicates (same name). It will do this only to products of the configurable and leave only one. If you check for all the simple products, you will see there is one that remains.

When you upload an image in the backend, even if it is the same image, Magento will append a number to the image name and make it unique.